# Here Maps: Failed to set up map cache

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting Failed to set up map cache while instantiating

NMAMapView* mapView = [[NMAMapView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

Comment: hi did you find the solution? @Rameez Raja

Comment: Yes, i was missing NMABundle file.